# Node.js, multiple MySQL insertions

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sql-insert

i want to do multiple MySQL insertions in a specefic ordner for my server-client-application.

```
var con = createDatabaseConnection();

function createDatabaseConnection() {
return (mysql.createConnection({
        host: // hostIp,
        user: // user,
        password: //pw,
        database: //databasename
    });
}

function writeFoo(fooObject) {
   var sql = // prepare sql insert for fooObject;
   con.query(sql, function (err) {
      // ? Is inserted data ready to use ?
   }
});

function writeBar(barObject) {
   var sql = // prepare sql insert for barObject;
   con.query(sql, function (err) {
      // ? Is inserted data ready to use ?
   });
});

// Both arrays containing an unpredictable amount of objects
var fooArray = [];
var barArray = [];
```

The crucial point is that I have to be absolutely sure, that the `fooObject`s in the `fooArray` are inserted before the `barArray` gets inserted. Because the SQL INSERT statement which is used in `writeBar()` contains a SELECT statement which has to find the data inserted in `writeFoo()`.
And at any moment an event could happen (client sends data that needs to be inserted), that would need this functionality too.

The real situation is a bit more complex, but i think that's the main problem at the moment.

Comment: here is good lib https://caolan.github.io/async/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain them in a [promise](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/promises-in-node-js-an-alternative-to-callbacks/), this way you will make sure every call is in order, ex:

```
var con;
function createDatabaseConnection() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        mysql.createConnection({
            host: hostIp,
            user: user,
            password: pw,
            database: databasename
        }, function(err, res){
            if(err) reject(err);
            else resolve(res);
        });
    });
}

function writeFoo(fooObject) {
    let sql = fooObject;
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        con.query(sql, function (err, res) {
            if(err) reject(err);
            else resolve(res);
        });
    });
}

function writeBar(barObject) {
    let sql = barObject;
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        con.query(sql, function (err, res) {
            if(err) reject(err);
            else resolve(res);
        });
    });
}

createDatabaseConnection()
    .catch(function (error) {
        // connection failed
        // log info
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(0);
    })
    .then(function (res) {
        con = res;
        return writeFoo(fooObject);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        // writeFoo(fooObject) failed
        // log info
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(0);
    })
    .then(function () {
        return writeBar(barObject);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        // writeBar(barObject) failed
        // log info
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(0);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Not going to say ORM's are always best but http://docs.sequelizejs.com/ works well with node. There is a bulk insert option right in there.